# How can I store the results of a SQL query as a hash with unique keys?

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I have a query that returns multiple rows:

```
select id,status from store where last_entry = <given_date>;
```

The returned rows look like:

```
id      status
-----------------
1131A   correct
1132B   incorrect
1134G   empty
```

I want to store the results like this:

```
$rows = [
    {
        ID1     => '1131A',
        status1 => 'correct'
    }, 
    {
        ID2     => '1132B',
        status2 => 'incorrect'
    },
    {
        ID3     => '1134G',
        status3 => 'empty'
    }
];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a hash of hash in Perl. What you do is

1. Iterate over the results of your query.
2. Split each entry by tab
3. Create a hash with the id as key and status as value
4. Now to store the hash created by each such query you create another hash. Here the key could be something like 'given_date' in your case so you could write

   `$parent_hash{given_date}=\%child_hash`

This will results in the parent hash having a **reference** of each query result.

For more you can refer to these resources:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-array-reference-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref).

Here is part of script that does what you want:

```
my $rows;
while(my $hash_ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    push @$rows, $hash_ref;
}
```

Comment: i am getting the result as $VAR1 [ { 'ID' =>'1131A', 'STATUS' =>'correct'}, {'ID' =>'1132B', 'STATUS' =>'incorrect'}] what i would like is the key of the hash to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing a `Slice` option to `DBI`'s [`selectall_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_arrayref):

```
my $results = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
    'select id,status from store where last_entry = ?',
    { Slice => {} },
    $last_entry
);
```

This will return an array reference with each row stored in a hash. Note that since hash keys must be unique, you will run into problems if you have duplicate column names in your query.

Comment: column name is same, which is the trouble for me how could i replace the column name which is the key in this case with a unique value?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have an array reference, which means each row can be identified by its index. For example, you can get the ID of the second row with `$results->[1]{id}`. If that's not enough, please edit your question to explain exactly why you think you need the keys to be different for each row (although I can't think of any good reason to do it that way, and it will probably make your code unnecessarily complex).

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
# select the data as an array of hashes - retured as an arrayref
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($the_query, {Slice => {}}, @any_search_params);

# now make the id keys unique
my $i = 1;
foreach my $row ( @$rows) {
   # remove each column and assign the value to a uniquely named column
   # by adding a numeric suffix
   $row->{"ID" . $i} = delete $row->{ID};
   $row->{"status" . $i} = delete $row->{status};
   $i += 1;
}
```

Add your own error checking.

So you said "save as a hash," but your example is an array of hashes. So there would be a slightly different method for a hash of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of question that raises an immediate red flag. It's somewhat of an odd request to want a collection (array/array reference) of data structures that are heterogeneous---that's the whole point of a collection. If you tell us what you intend to do with the data rather than what you want the data to look like, we can probably suggest a better solution.